# Gson json object error IllegalStateException - Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gson

I'm trying to parse a json string like the one below but I'm getting an error when the rest endpoint is hit

Failed to read HTTP message: 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

```
{
  "resources": [
{
  "resourceType": "Car",
  "resourceId": "Car1"
},
{
  "resourceType": "Truck",
  "resourceId": "Truck1"
}
],
 "topics": [
   "some_data",
   "some_event"
]
}


@PostMapping(value = "/subscribe", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void create(@RequestBody String subscriptionRequest)
        throws Exception
{

    SubscriptionRequest request = new Gson().fromJson(subscriptionRequest, SubscriptionRequest.class); 

    if ( request.getResources().isEmpty() || request.getTopics().isEmpty() )
    {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
    }
    other code ....
}


public class SubscriptionRequest
{
private List<Resources> resources = null;

private List<String> topics = null;

public SubscriptionRequest()
{
    super();
}

public List<Resources> getResources()
{
    return this.resources;
}

public void setResources(List<Resources> resources)
{
    this.resources = resources;
}

public List<String> getTopics()
{
    return this.topics;
}

public void setTopics(List<String> topics)
{
    this.topics = topics;
}

}

public class Resources {

    private List<Resource> resources = null;

    private int resourceId;

    public Resources() 
    {
        super();
    }

    public List<Resource> getResources() {
        return this.resources;
    }

    public void setResources(List<Resource> resources) {
        this.resources = resources;
    }
}

public class Resource {

    private String resourceType;

    private String resourceId;

    public Resource()
    {
        super();
    }

    public Resource(String resourceType, String resourceId) 
    {
        this.resourceType = resourceType;
        this.resourceId = resourceId;
    }

    public String getResourceType() 
    {
        return this.resourceType;
    }

    public void setResourceType(String resourceType) 
    {
        this.resourceType = resourceType;
    }

    public String getResourceId() 
    {
        return this.resourceId;
    }

    public void setResourceId(String resourceId) 
    {
        this.resourceId = resourceId;
    }
}

public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
  registry.addMapping("/**")
      .allowedOrigins("*")
      .allowedMethods("POST", "GET",  "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE")
      .allowedHeaders("X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin");
}

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    GsonHttpMessageConverter msgConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create(); 
    msgConverter.setGson(gson);
    converters.add(msgConverter);
}
}
```

Comment: How the Resources class looks like? Why its name is plural?

Comment: I have added Resources class

Comment: What I see now is that you need to have List<Resource> SubscriptionRequest class to match your expected payload. You don't need Resources class I would say.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you'd be injecting the deserialized type directly:

```
public void create(@RequestBody SubscriptionRequest subscriptionRequest)
```

and Spring takes care of deserializing it. Here, you expect a string, so Spring attempt to read the JSON input, which is an object, and deserialize it as a string, so it breaks (*Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT*).

Try surrounding the entire input in double quotes:

```
"{
  "resources": [
{
  "resourceType": "Car",
  "resourceId": "Car1"
},
{
  "resourceType": "Truck",
  "resourceId": "Truck1"
}
],
 "topics": [
   "some_data",
   "some_event"
]
}"
```

This will likely resolve your immediate issue, but isn't what you want to do. Instead you should likely leave it to Spring as described above.